# Do I need to care about type of encoding if the JSON file is going to share across different platforms

Tags: java, android, encoding, gson

Currently, I'm using `gson`, to perform serialization on Objects. It works pretty fine in single platform (Windows).

However, if I were gonna to share the json file across different platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac, Android), do I need to specific type of encoding (UTF-8) being used? (There will be foreign language characters in json file)? Or, the default encoding used by BufferedWriter/BufferedReader will be same across all platforms?

```
public static boolean write(A a, File file) {
    final Gson gson = new Gson();
    String string = gson.toJson(a); 

    try {
        //If the constructor throws an exception, the finally block will NOT execute
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        try {
            writer.write(string);
        } finally {
            //no need to check for null
            //any exceptions thrown here will be caught by 
            //the outer catch block
            writer.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static A load(File file) {
    // Copy n paste from newInstance.
    final Gson gson = new Gson();

    try {
        //If the constructor throws an exception, the finally block will NOT execute
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        try {
            return gson.fromJson(reader, A.class);
        } finally {
            //no need to check for null
            //any exceptions thrown here will be caught by 
            //the outer catch block
            reader.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex){
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add to it, FileReader and FileWriter are platform specific. Prefer ObjectStreams instead. Again, my score does not permit me to put it as a comment:(